# List and Library are not display in SharePoint designer 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

When i try to open SharePoint designer (2010) the list and library are not shown, Its throws error like ‘testSplist’ is Broken.

How to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow the below steps to resolve this issue.**

1. Open the SharePoint PowerShell command prompt.
2. Write the following code on SharePoint powershell.

   $web = Get-SPWeb http://[yoursite]

   $list = $web.Lists["Your Broken List"]

   $list.Delete()
3. Once you done restart the SharePoint designer.
4. Now open the SharePoint designer it will show the all list and library.

Comment: am glad to help you